# How to POST data with cURL to an iframe?

Tags: php, forms, curl

Can I post data with cURL to an iframe using PHP?

Note : Consider that php curl script and the page with iframe that contains the form, are both in my server. The iframe includes a form from a remote server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confusing server side and client side here. Obviously you can use iframes and PHP/CURL. Just put your form code in the a page that renders to the iframe and when the user submits the form, process the form, send the curl request and the process the return as you normally would.